# TIMEVALUE in Excel convert greater than 24 hours

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I would like to convert text time into real time via TIMEVALUE function in Excel. Time up to 24:00 converts fine, for time greater than 24 hours it  converts into hours but excluding 24, I already used custom format [h]:mm, please see my printscreen.

[image]

Comment: What time do you expect `25:15` and `49:00` to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the [TIMEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0B615C12-33D8-4431-BF3D-F3EB6D186645) for text-to-time conversion. Use the [VALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257D0108-07DC-437D-AE1C-BC2D3953D8C2) instead and format as `[hh]:mm`.

[image]

If you want to convert in-place, then use the Data ribbon's Text-to-Columns command.